# Nuget restore fails on VSO 2017 build for CORE packages

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I have previously created and built a simple .net core nuget package and pushed it to our internal nuget (hosted inside our VSO). Now I wanted to reference it from another core project. This worked fine locally.

I then go onto defining my build. Here are the details:

- Agent is "Hosted VS2017"
- Process

  - Nuget Installer (Version 3.5, pointed at my solution file, nuget.config contains my package sources)
  - Thats it! We never get any further

When I run the build I get this error on the Nuget Installer bit:

```
[command]C:\a\_tasks\....\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive C:\a\1\s\...sln -ConfigFile C:\a\1\s\...\nuget.config
Failed to load msbuild Toolset
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Things I've Tried**:

- If the nuget version is lower than 3.5 I get a 401 unauthorized
- If the nuget version is lower than 3.5 and I don't reference a dotnetcore nuget it works
- I added my own credentials to the packageStoreCredentials section of the nuget.config with no effect (I am an admin on VSO)
- I tried using nuget 4 by including its exe in the checkin and referencing that from the Nuget Installer, but I then get "Error: Iac.Repository/nuget.exe failed. spawn Iac.Repository/nuget.exe ENOENT"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share the detail build log after you using Nuget 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use NuGet 4.0 instead of 3.5 since your project is based on VS2017.

Now NuGet 4.0 is available for NuGet Installer task, so you can select the version directly and needn’t checkin the version to your source code.

[image]

For some VSTS accounts don't show nuget 4.0, I creates [a new issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3966), you can follow up.

Another way to use NuGet 4.0 for TFVC project:

1. Checkin the nugget 4.0 in source code, such as `nuget4.0.exe`.
2. In Get source step, map nuget4.0.exe.

[image]

3. In nugget installer task, specify nugget.exe path as `$(build.sourcesDirectory)/nuget4.0.exe`.

[image]

Comment: Thats strange, I only have options for 3.3.0 and 3.5. Do I have to do any extra config do you know? Its a visualstudio.com account, not a local install

Comment: Yeah, I just checked the other account of VSTS, it only has 3.3 and 3.5. But For the account I am using didn't do any extra config and it show version 4.0. So I also give another way to use nuget 4.0 in my answer.

Comment: Already tried that unfortunately - I'm getting
"Error: Iac.Repository/nuget.exe failed. spawn Iac.Repository/nuget.exe ENOENT"

Comment: Did you set **Path to NuGet.exe** as `$(build.sourcesDirectory)/nuget.exe`?

Comment: Its in a directory under there, but yes, I definitely referenced the file correctly

Comment: I added the screenshot of path to nuget.exe setting in my answer. Please set with similar format and have a try.

Comment: On the other hand, I create the issue some VSTS accounts can't show nuget 4.0 https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3966, you can follow up.

Comment: Thanks! I did move it to the same folder as you and tried again but with the same result :(

Comment: Now Nuget 4.0 is available for every VSTS accounts. Please check with your account (reopen) if you can find it in NuGet Installer task?

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: I was forced to move away from the core route - I can see the nuget 4 option in vso now at least.

The custom pointing to the exe did not fix anything though.

I'll try to get the core stuff running again soon to check

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and found this thread.

After reviewing Marina's comments, I was able to get it working. All I did was alter the path based on the comments.

$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Builds\Tools\nuget.exe

Comment: This should better be a comment to the referenced answer, rather than an answer of its own. (But I know you have not yet enough reputation to comment)